# How to exclude packages/directories from py.test?

Tags: pytest

You can use `-k` to filter out tests following a certain name pattern/predicate, but can you filter out tests under a certain package or directory?  Didn't spot any relevant flags in the documentation but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: This question was answered - perhaps you want to accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the location as an argument for py.test:

```
py.test test/comp_1/
```

Of course you can also combine this with `-k` switch:

```
py.test -k slow test/comp_1/
```

Does this answer you question?